# Why is the if statement not executed?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I have an assignment where I have to ask a user if they want to add a new student to a program or not. 
I set a variable to hold the user command and then: 
If it's a Yes (1) the program will ask the user to enter a name and id, if not, the program exits.

```
students = []

def get_students_titleCase():
    students_titleCase = []
    for student in students:
        students_titleCase = student["name"].title()
    return students_titleCase

def print_students_titlecase():
    students_titleCase = get_students_titleCase()
    print(students_titleCase)

def add_student(name , student_id = 000):
    student = {"name" : name , "student_id": student_id }
    students.append(student)

user_command = input("Do You Want to Add a Student Name?\n1- Yes\n2- No\n")
#user_command = 1
if user_command == 1:
    student_list = get_students_titleCase()
    student_name = input("Enter Student Name: ")
    student_id = input("Enter Student ID: ")
    add_student(student_name, student_id)
    print_students_titlecase()
```

Comment: Because `user_command` does not equal `1`... (hint: what does `input` return?)

Comment: but i enter 1 ???

Comment: But what does [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) give ??? (here's another hint: read the documentation...)

Comment: idk what u mean , when i run the program and it comes to the line of User_command
"Do u want to add ... " text is displayed and i press 1

Comment: `If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.` <--- documentation (you can find this with a simple google search).

Comment: Here's one final hint for you. `1` is not the same as `"1"`.

Comment: sorry , didnt know that it returns a string :D

Comment: ok so i solved it by changing the if condition to `code` if user_command == '1' `code` 
but what if i want the user to enter a 1 not a '1' ?

Comment: @ShaDiliX `input` will always return a string. If you want to interpret the user's input as a number, parse the string they give you with `int`. Note, `int` will throw an error if the string you give it can't be interpreted as a number.

Answer (score 1):

Behaviour would be as expected if executed over `python2.7` but since its `Python 3` where `input` returns the `str` type like `raw_input` returns in `python 2.7`. Also note that `raw_input` is **not** introduced in `python 3`.

Therefore considering the above point you have to change the code a bit to make that work.

```
# Compare against string instead of int
if user_command == '1':
```

However if you still want to compare against number of `int` type then

```
if user_command.isdigit() and int(user_command) == 1:
```